# How can I prove that the chronological (=time-ordered) product of two scalar fields is Lorentz invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, causality, propagator, covariance

In my course of introduction to QFT, one of the questions is prove that the chronological product (time-ordered product)  of two scalar fields is Lorentz invariant and I'm having trouble coming up with an answer. The chronological product is here defined as follows:
$$ T(\phi(x)\phi(y)) ~=~ :\phi(x)\phi(y): ~+~ D_F(x-y) $$
Where $D_F$ is the Feynman propagator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operators commute if they are spacelike separated, so that if $(x-y)^2 > 0$, then their ordering is completely irrelevant and the time-ordering operator does absolutely nothing to the product.

If they are timelike separated, then their causal relationship is Lorentz invariant. More mathematically, if $(x-y)^2 < 0$ then $\theta(x^0-y^0)$ is invariant under Lorentz transformations that are continuously connected to the identity. **Proof left to the reader**.

It should then be clear that the time-ordering operator is Lorentz invariant.